# Getting data form 2 tables and summing values of the result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with information: **ID, persona_id, total_amount**
The persona ID can repeat dozen of times. So i get all the one persons id total_amount with query:

```
select d.id as debt_id, p.name as persona, sum(d.total_amount) as total_amount 
from debt d 
     join persons p on d.persona_id = p.id group by p.name
```

I want to get data from each table in one query and do aritmethic propertys with the total_amount column and return it as 1 tabel.

TABLE 1

```
id persons_id total_amount
1   2         50
2   3         100
3   2         200
4   5         300
5   1         500
```

TABLE 2

```
id persons_id total_amount
1   2         25
2   1         100
3   5         50
4   3         100
5   4         300
```

As a result i want to get the 2 tables comined with arithmetic operation (-, +, / , * ) of Total amount columns.Basicaly a change to get the ending result total amount in form i want for different cases.

What worked for me based on JohnHC answear was :

```
select c.id, c.persona_id, c.total_amount - d.total_amount as new_total

from (          select c.id , c.persona_id, sum(c.total_amount) as total_amount from credit c
                join persons p on c.persona_id = p.id
                group by p.name) c
inner join (    select d.id, d.persona_id, sum(d.total_amount) as total_amount from debt d
                join persons p on d.persona_id = p.id 
                group by p.name) d

on c.persona_id = d.persona_id
group by c.id, c.persona_id
```

Comment: First question I think should be "Why have you got 2 tables with exactly the same structure?"

Comment: @RiggsFolly since the structure presented doesn't match the query, I'm going to assume the OP "left out" some information to "make it easier" for us to read. We may even have 3 different tables.

Comment: I have 2 tables with exact same structure but holds in one table holds amount of wood picked at site a but other holds coal amount at site b but person who does the job can be the same at both sites. Myb the problem is in dividing information into 2 tables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the total, try:

```
select id, person_id, sum(total_amount)
from
(
select id, person_id, total_amount
from table1
union all
select id, person_id, total_amount
from table2
)
group by id, person_id
```

If you want to do other things, try:

```
select t1.id, t1.person_id, t1.total_amount [+ - / *] t2.total_amount as new_total
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.person_id
group by t1.id, t1.person_id
```

Comment: Thank you for help after some minutes playing around with your answear i managed to get what i wanted. I updated the post with the solution that helped me get data in form i wanted.